# multiple content security policies on play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, xss, content-security-policy

Using play framework, I would like to apply different policies to incoming requests to allow for external html + script to run on my website. This is necessary for some third party integrations who provide you with their own html + script content, for the user to interact with, and which has to be delivered via your original website.

The policy should be defined based on some condition, primarily subdomain. In filter specification, there is only one global [`play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SecurityHeaders) that affects the whole site. But I don't want to loosen that. Requests to some particular 
`thirdparty.website.com` on my `website.com` should get a loosened policy or even no policy at all, but the remaining website should continue with the tight policy.

I appreciate any ideas or help.

Comment: You probably have to write your own filter. In this filter you can check the `request` object for the headers, domain, etc. and then apply the specific headers on the response. See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/headers/SecurityHeadersFilter.scala#L134-L137 how Play implemented it's SecurityHeadersFilter

Comment: Thanks @mkurz, the way you have described worked great.

Comment: Good to hear I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example if anyone needs it. (**Thanks @mkurz for the pointer** )

Very simple, SecurityHeadersFilter apply is replicated here and security headers are skipped if host and path criteria are both satisfied. If not, the original behavior is preserved.

```
class ConditionalSecurityHeadersFilter @Inject() (implicit config: SecurityHeadersConfig) extends SecurityHeadersFilter(config) {
 override def apply (next: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { req =>
    val HostPattern: Regex = "..some regex..".r
    val PathsToBypass: List[String] = [...]
    import play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution.Implicits.trampoline
    req.host.toLowerCase match {
      case HostPattern(...) =>
          if (PathsToBypass.map{path =>
                path.r.findFirstIn(req.path)
              }.count { p => p.isDefined } > 0)
            next(req)
          else
            next(req).map(_.withHeaders(headers(req): _*))
      case _ =>  next(req).map(_.withHeaders(headers(req): _*))
    }
  }
}
```

Also, add the filter into the `Filters`

```
class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter,
                         allowedHostsFilter: AllowedHostsFilter,
                         gzipFilter: GzipFilter,
                         customSecurityHeadersFilter: ConditionalSecurityHeadersFilter
                        ) extends HttpFilters {
  def filters = Seq(corsFilter,
    allowedHostsFilter,
    gzipFilter,
    customSecurityHeadersFilter
  )
}
```